# Sql query to find sorted and group by id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, qsqlquery

I have one table named personAndBookinMapping
columns are :
**mappingId person_id  book_id intreset_score book_name**

Now I have to find top two record based on interest_score of each person_id.
basically response should be like below :

**mapping_id person_id book_id intreset_score book_name**
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjx3K.png)

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: How do you handle ties?

Answer (score 0):

You would typically do this using window functions, which are available in MySQL 8+.

```
select pabm.*
from (select pabm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person_id order by interest_score desc) as seqnum
      from personAndBookinMapping pabm
     ) pabm
where seqnum <= 2;
```

In earlier versions, variables are the most consistent method:

```
select pabm.*
from (select pabm.*,
             (@rn := if(@p = person_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@p := person_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select pabm.*
            from personAndBookinMapping pabm
            order by person_id, interest_score desc
           ) pabm cross join
           (select @p := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) pabm
where rn <= 2;
```